# storing R code in a list

Tags: r, list

I'm making a number of conditional assignments in a large dataframe. (here's an example with made up numbers)

```
x<-data.frame(average=c(2,6,7,4,9),bill=c(3,7,5,2,5),averagebill=c(8,2,5,3,4),averagecost=c(1,6,4,7,8),xcount=c(4,5,2,8,1),ycount=c(7,4,2,8,8))
```

In pseudo-code, a short version of what I am doing is:

```
if xcount > 3
   newaverage<-averagecost
   newbill<-averagebill
else if ycount > 3
   newaverage<-average
   newbill<-bill
```

One way to do it is with nested ifelse() functions

```
y<-within(x, { newaverage<-ifelse(xcount > 3,averagecost,
                      ifelse(ycount > 3,average,NA))

               newbill<-ifelse(xcount > 3,averagebill,
                      ifelse(ycount > 3,bill,NA))
    })
```

This works but my actual code is assigning a lot more than 2 variables and it becomes repetitive and hard to read. Also, ifelse() isn't really necessary. This is another way:

```
y<-within(x, { newaverage[xcount > 3] <- averagecost[xcount > 3]
               newbill[xcount > 3] <- averagebill[xcount > 3]

               newaverage[xcount <= 3 & ycount > 3] <- average[xcount <= 3 & ycount > 3]
               newbill[xcount <= 3 & ycount > 3] <- bill[xcount <= 3 & ycount > 3]
    })
```

This is better, but the "xcount <= 3 & ycount > 3" is still too repetitive. I discovered I could simplify with a list:

```
z<-list("xcon"=x$xcount>3,"ycon"=x$xcount<=3 & x$ycount>3)
y<-within(x, { newaverage[z[["xcon"]]] <- averagecost[z[["xcon"]]]
               newbill[z[["xcon"]]]    <- averagebill[z[["xcon"]]]

               newaverage[z[["ycon"]]] <- average[z[["ycon"]]]
               newbill[z[["ycon"]]]    <- bill[z[["ycon"]]]
    })
```

As you can see this is easier to read and easier to maintain. If I need to change the conditions, I just edit the list once instead of going through every assignment.

**My question is, is this actually a good practice? I never knew code could be stored in a list, and I can see this being useful in the future when I have repetitive code. Or is there an even more elegant way to do this?**

edit: added x$ to the last example

Comment: You must have attached `x`, because you can't create such a `z`.

Comment: You're not actually storing code in a list, your storing vectors. If you enter `z$xcon` in your console you'll see a boolean vector.

Comment: +1, though simpler, more natural variable names would be nice here.

Comment: You can store unevaluated expressions in a list. Take a look at `parse` and `eval`.

Comment: How does `if countx > 3` not give `Error: unexpected symbol in "if xcount"` for you?

Comment: @MatthewPlourde, you are correct, it's supposed to be x$xcount and not just xcount.

Comment: @shujaa, thanks for that insight, didn't realize they were actual boolean vectors, I kept thinking it was just inserting the code.

Comment: @Georg, I know eval(parse(text=)) can be used but I also know it's bad practice and should be avoided. That's why I found this solution.